# How to rotate a symbol depending on an attribute

Tags: sld

I would like to rotate a symbol depending on an attribute "HEIGHT_FT".

The rotation I would like is:

angle = -360 + (<HEIGHT_FT>*0.3).

How do I add this rotation to the following SLD-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se">
<NamedLayer>
<se:Name>Rotated obstacles by height</Name>
<UserStyle>
  <Name>Rotated symbols by height</Name>
  <FeatureTypeStyle>
    <Rule>
      <Name>Rotated symbols</Name>
      <Description>
        <Title>Rotated obstacle</Title>
      </Description>
      <PointSymbolizer>
        <Graphic>
          <ExternalGraphic>
            <OnlineResource xlink:href="obst1.svg?fill=#120ef6;fill-opacity=1;outline=#232323;outline-opacity=1;outline-width=0" xlink:type="simple"/>
            <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
          </ExternalGraphic>
          <!--Plain SVG fallback, no parameters-->
          <ExternalGraphic>
            <OnlineResource xlink:href="obst1.svg" xlink:type="simple"/>
            <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
          </ExternalGraphic>
          <!--Well known marker fallback-->
          <Mark>
            <WellKnownName>square</WellKnownName>
            <Fill>
              <SvgParameter name="fill">#120ef6</SvgParameter>
            </Fill>
            <Stroke>
              <SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</SvgParameter>
              <SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</SvgParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </Mark>
          <Size>17</Size>
        </Graphic>
      </PointSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
  </FeatureTypeStyle>
</UserStyle>
```

Comment: <Rotation>
                <Add>
                  <Literal>-360</Literal>
                  <Mul>
                    <PropertyName>HEIGHT_FT</PropertyName>
                    <Literal>0.3</Literal>
                  </Mul>
                </Add>
              </Rotation>

Answer (score 4):

After `<Size>17</Size>` line, try inserting:

```
    <Rotation>
      <ogc:Add>
        <ogc:Literal>-360</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Mul>
         <ogc:PropertyName>HEIGHT_FT</ogc:PropertyName>
         <ogc:Literal>0.3</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:Mul>
      </ogc:Add>
    </Rotation>
```